# C++ - Easiest way to convert possible numeric values in an ASCII char array to characters

Tags: c++, arrays

What's the easiest way to count a character array as ASCII values and if it contains numeric values then convert them to the `char` and show them as a `char` array, not the values? Such input may be `1003297` the output will be `d a`. what is the simplest and easiest way to do that?

Actually, I am trying to solve [**UVa problem 444 - Encoder Decoder**](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/4/p444.pdf). I've done half of it. But The problem is I can't convert any `int` number input to `char` array.

I managed to convert the characters to their ASCII values and reverse each and every ASCII values and showing it by reversing the whole array but the vice versa I couldn't do it and stuck here for three days and keep searching. I am taking input `char` array so if I take numeric values, it will be taken as a character also but I need to store all the numeric values to an `int` array and assuming that all these numbers are ASCII values, I need to show that the `char` values for that `int` array through a `char` array. And one more thing that the time limit is `3` second. I know it's large but I need the easiest and simplest way to do that.

---

This is my incomplete solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str [80];
    int arr [80];
    char intStr[80];
    int b;
    string a, finale;

    cout << "Your String : ";
    cin.getline( str, 80, '\n' );

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[0] < 48 || str[0] > 57 || str[i] == 32 && str[i] != 13 )
        {
            arr[i] = str[i];
            b = i;
        }
        else if(str[0] > 48 && str[0] < 57)
        {
            arr[i] = str[i];
            b = i;
            goto encode;
        }
    }

    decode:

    for(int j = b; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        itoa(arr[j], intStr, 10);
        a = a + strrev(intStr);
    }
    cout << a;

    encode:

    for(int j = b; j > 0; j--)
    {
        //itoa(arr[j], intStr, 10);
        atoi(arr[j]);
        a = a + strrev(intStr);
    }
    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all stop using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you by e.g. `48` mean the character `'0'` then *say* so. Secondly, instead of checking ranges, use [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). Thirdly, start using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of character arrays. Fourthly, don't use `goto`. Lastly, [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Avoid magic numbers as `48`, `57`, `32` or `13`, prefer human readable `'0'`, `'9'`, `'\n'`.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)`: you recompute length at each iteration. `std::string::size()` would avoid that computation.

Comment: Should not `"1003297"` be `"d a"`?

Comment: Yes if input is 1003297 the output should "d a" .if i use in condition if like 
    if(str[0]<'0' || str[o]>'9'  && str[i]!= '\n')
will it Work Fine?
I have Corrected For Loop now.
And Now What is The Way or simplest and easiest way to Count numeric number as Ascii values and output the ascii values as Char array?

Comment: @Some programmer dude
Okay Caught Your Point But Got My Existing Complexity Reduced but What is The Solution That i asked to Count the Numeric Number as ascii values and converting them back to the character and show Output?and What would be the simplest and easiest way?

Comment: First of all, don't expect us to give you a complete solution. We're here to help you learn, not do your homework or competitive programming problems for you. If you follow Some programmer dude's suggestions, you will make your own life a lot easier. What you need to do is to go through the string one character at a time, keeping track of the current number. For each character, you can convert it to its numerical value by subtracting `'0'`. Then, append that digit to your number using some mathematical calculations. When the number becomes too big, you know you should start a new number.

Comment: Thnx For The Suggestion and explanation and i am not expecting the whole Solution not even now--i am going through the Suggestions and finding out my problems and solve them in my own way--My Concept getting litle bit more clear by your explanation....Thank you for your cordial support--@Fei Xiang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can certainly be made simpler...

First, usage of raw character arrays in C++ should be reserved to low level operations. Here you are just processing an input string, so it should be a plain `std::string`.

Then the correct way is to accumulate input decimal digits until you reach an acceptable ascii code, and when you get one you add it at the end of your output string.

Finally, building a string one character at a time is inefficient: you should first gather everything in a `std::vector` and only at the end build the string. Code could be as simple as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line;            // input line
    vector<char> out;       // gather converted characters
    char res = 0;           // to compute the ascii values
    std::getline(cin, line);
    for (char c: line) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {         // only process decimal digits
            res = 10 * res + (c - '0');
            if (res >= ' ') {               // Ok, we have a valid ASCII code
                out.push_back(res);
                res = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (res != 0) {                // assume that non numeric act as separators
            out.push_back(res);             // whatever the input value (allows control chars)
            res = 0;
        }
    }
    string a(out.begin(), out.end());       // build a string from the vector
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Trying to Run These Whole Code But Only Black Screen Appears And Didnt Show Any Output For Any Input By this Code?!

Comment: I gave it `1003297`Enter and got `d a`.

Comment: Nothing Happens I am Trying It on codeblocks 17.12. After Build It Says a Note In the log File
"C:\Users\Prince Porosh\Documents\f.cpp|12|warning: range-based 'for' loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|"

Comment: Does This Kind Of For Not Supported by Codeblocks??Or IN Which IDE you are Running Plz Let me Know.

Comment: @user9903364: no IDE for that, just vim to edit the code and Clang to compile it in C++11 mode.

Comment: Thank You Its Working Now ---Getting Huge Clue From Your Code And Learning a Lot And Can Generate My Own Ideas Too...Thank YOu very much For Helping me in Such a Way--